# PhantomJs - knockout is not loading

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, phantomjs

We are generating Html Reports whose data will be bound in Run-time from the Database using Knockout Js.
I'm using PhantomJs (calling it as child process from NodeJs) to render Pdf of those reports.

The final Pdf file is not having any data which the Knockout is supposed to bind.

I've deployed those reports in IIS and am sending that path to node and then to rasterize.js of phantom.

The original Html if opened in normal browser works fine with all the data.

I've tried including both JQuery and Knockout files again in rasterize.js like:

```
    page.injectJs('jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
    page.injectJs('knockout-3.0.0.js');
```

but no results.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If those scripts are included in the page, then you shouldn't to it again through the script. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that the problem lies with bad html(of the image binded) in that report. I removed the image and it works fine. But I get the problem whenever I bind any of the images and we need to bind images.

Comment: What do you mean with *bind*? Do you mean `Function.prototype.bind`? If yes, then you need a shim.

Comment: @user3490000 If it is not too late, take a look at [this article](http://www.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/), specifically the section named `Loading/Injecting images into the PDF content` where author talks about how to handle images